# xcode4 run keyboard shortcut?

Tags: xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, xcode3to4

cmd-enter was the hot key for "run" for xcode3?

What is the hot key for run in xcode4?
Or can I set one for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, the "Run" hotkey is cmd+R, but under preferences(cmd+, by default, or just click the apple icon in the top left and select Preferences when running xcode), you can change any of the keybindings to however you like

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice chart see the most useful shortcuts : 
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html

And the Run command is now CMD-R